# Problem with changes package and documentclass llncs

Tags: document-classes, lncs, changes

I would like to use the `changes` package to highlight changes I made between two versions. For most document classes this works nicely. However, for `llncs` [from Springer](ftp://ftp.springer.de/pub/tex/latex/llncs/latex2e/llncs2e.zip) the command `\listofchanges` does not work properly, i.e. the header is generated but the changes are not listed.

This looks as expected, but does not use the desired document class.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}
\listofchanges
\replaced{This is the article class}{Some old text}
\end{document}
```

Here, the header for the list of changes is printed, but the changes themselves are not.

```
\documentclass{llncs}
\usepackage{changes}
\begin{document}
\listofchanges
\replaced{This is the llncs class}{Some old text}
\end{document}
```

Below my package versions as given by `\listfiles`:

```
 *File List*
   llncs.cls    2015/06/24 v2.20 
 LaTeX document class for Lecture Notes in Computer Science
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
multicol.sty    2014/10/28 v1.8i multicolumn formatting (FMi)
aliascnt.sty    2009/09/08 v1.3 Alias counters (HO)
remreset.sty    
 changes.sty    2014/10/15 v2.0.3 changes package
 xkeyval.sty    2014/05/25 v2.7 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/05/25 v2.7 key=value parser (HA)
 xifthen.sty    2009/04/17 v1.3 Extended ifthen features
    etex.sty    1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
  ifthen.sty    2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
 ifmtarg.sty    2009/09/02 v1.2a check for an empty argument
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pdfcolmk.sty    2008/08/11 v1.2 Color support for pdfTeX via marks (HO)
    ulem.sty    2012/05/18
truncate.sty    2001/08/20  ver 3.6
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Comment: This looks like an expansion and fragile command issue

Comment: I don't have any familiarity with `changes` so I can't answer your question but another way of doing this that does not require any internal mark-up is to use [latexidff](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexdiff). The caveat is that the diffs sometimes fail.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your comment. I'm aware of latexdiff, but the `changes' package gives you a summary of the changes

Comment: I don't see a table of contents either, if I insert `\tableofcontents`. The *changes* package uses the same mechanism. Is this behavior of *llncs* on purpose?